# SQL Hierarchy String Column to XML

Tags: sql, xml, hierarchy

Trying to convert a Hierarchy string column in SQL to and XML output

I have this...

```
    HIERARCHY_Column                                                  VALUE_Column
    Header_1 > Question_A                                             Answer_A
    Header_1 > Subheader_1 > Question_B                               Answer_B
    Header_1 > Subheader_2 > Question_C                               Answer_C
    Header_1 > Subheader_2 > Subheader_3 > Question_D                 Answer_D
    Header_1 > Subheader_4 > Subheader_5 > Question_E                 Answer_E
    Header_1 > Subheader_4 > Subheader_5 > Question_F                 Answer_F
    Header_1 > Subheader_6 > Subheader_7 > Subheader_8  > Question_G  Answer_G
    Header_1 > Subheader_6 > Subheader_7 > Subheader_9  > Question_H  Answer_H
```

I want this output

```
<Header_1>
  <Question_A>Answer_A</Question_A>
  <SubHeader_1>
      <Question_B>Answer_B</Question_B>
  </SubHeader_1>
  <SubHeader_2>
      <Question_C>Answer_C</Question_C>
      <SubHeader_3>
          <Question_D>Answer_D</Question_D>
      </SubHeader_3>    
  </SubHeader_2>
  <SubHeader_4>
      <SubHeader_5>
          <Question_E>Answer_E</Question_E>
          <Question_F>Answer_F</Question_F>
      </SubHeader_5>    
  </SubHeader_4>
  <SubHeader_6>
    <SubHeader_7>
        <SubHeader_8>
            <Question_G>Answer_G</Question_G>
            <Question_H>Answer_H</Question_H>
        </SubHeader_8>
    </SubHeader_7>  
  </SubHeader_6>
</Header_1>
```

The data is dynamic so the position and number of the subheaders will change daily per row. So the structure of the above example will change for each Header depending on which questions were answered.

Comment: The solution would be easy if you had a hierarchical entity with a `parent_id` column or similar.

Comment: Are you hoping to do this with only a SQL query?

Comment: Please provide sample data together with your DDL, best as MCVE. There is no easy-cheesy way for unlimited nesting by hierarchy... Provide your samle as consumable table and we will see if there's a hack for you :-)

Comment: Ahhh, I thought you are talking about [a real hierarchy column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-2017), but looking at your question again I get the feeling, that your data is right as above as chain of strings... Correct?

Comment: @Marathon55 Prefer SQL, but could use SSIS as well

Comment: @Shnugo Yes, the string with deliminator ">" represents a hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```sql
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, HierarchyColumn VARCHAR(1000),Content VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('Header_1 > Question_A','Answer_A')
                      ,('Header_1 > Subheader_1 > Question_B','Answer_B')
                      ,('Header_1 > Subheader_2 > Question_C','Answer_C')
                      ,('Header_1 > Subheader_2 > Subheader_3 > Question_D','Answer_D')
                      ,('Header_1 > Subheader_4 > Subheader_5 > Question_E','Answer_E')
                      ,('Header_1 > Subheader_4 > Subheader_5 > Question_F','Answer_F')
                      ,('Header_1 > Subheader_6 > Subheader_7 > Subheader_8  > Question_G','Answer_G')
                      ,('Header_1 > Subheader_6 > Subheader_7 > Subheader_9  > Question_H','Answer_H');

DECLARE @stmt VARCHAR(MAX)=' SELECT '
+ STUFF(
        (
            SELECT ',''' + t.Content + ''' AS ' + QUOTENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE(t.HierarchyColumn,' ',''),'>','/'))
            FROM @tbl t 
            ORDER BY ID
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1,1,'') + ' FOR XML PATH('''')';

EXEC( @stmt);
```

The trick is, to create this statement dynamically and execute it with `EXEC()`:

```sql
 SELECT 'Answer_A' AS [Header_1/Question_A]
       ,'Answer_B' AS [Header_1/Subheader_1/Question_B]
       ,'Answer_C' AS [Header_1/Subheader_2/Question_C]
       ,'Answer_D' AS [Header_1/Subheader_2/Subheader_3/Question_D]
       ,'Answer_E' AS [Header_1/Subheader_4/Subheader_5/Question_E]
       ,'Answer_F' AS [Header_1/Subheader_4/Subheader_5/Question_F]
       ,'Answer_G' AS [Header_1/Subheader_6/Subheader_7/Subheader_8/Question_G]
       ,'Answer_H' AS [Header_1/Subheader_6/Subheader_7/Subheader_9/Question_H] 
FOR XML PATH('')
```

The draw back might be, that you must rely on some sort order. I use `ID`, it might suffice to sort by your hierarchy column (alphanumerically).

Any other approach will get rather tough... Please come back if this does not help you out.

Comment: this gets me going in the right direction, much appreciated. I do however have characters in the hierarchy column that are invalid for XML identification ie: (, <, =.  I'll need to find a workaround that doesn't strip the data too much.  Thanks